# What's the pythonic way to wrap several functions in the same with statements

Tags: python, eval, fabric, with-statement, contextmanager

I am using the Python library, [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/index.html), to do some remote server maintenance. Fabric automatically outputs all of the responses to remote and local commands unless you wrap the command in a couple with statements. Like so, on a local machine,

```
with settings(warn_only='true'):
    with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
        output = local("uname -a", True)
```

or like this on a remote machine:

```
with settings(warn_only='true'):
    with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
        output = run("uname -a")
```

I am writing a long and complex task and find myself repeating those two with statements over and over again. I want to write a function called _mute() to prevent that repetition. It would let me do something like this:

```
def _mute(fabric_cmd, args):
    with settings(warn_only='true'):
        with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
            output = fabric_cmd(args)
    return output

def some_remote_task():
    # Run a remote task silently
    _mute(remote, 'uname -a')

def some_local_task():
    # Run a local task silently
    _mute(local, 'uname -a', True)
```

I've looked into some solutions and know that "eval" could do this for me. But every page I read about eval suggests that it's almost always a bad idea because of security issues. I looked into partials, but I couldn't figure out how to make an argument in my _mute function callable. I'm guessing there's a higher level Python concept I'm missing here. What's the pythonic way to go about doing this? Thanks for any direction you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The better solution would be for you to build your own context manager; by far the easiest way would be to use the [`contextlib.contextmanager` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def _mute():
    with settings(warn_only='true'):
        with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
            yield
```

Then use `_mute` as a context manager:

```
def some_remote_task():
    # Run a remote task silently
    with _mute():
        output = remote("uname -a")
```

This is a lot more compact and readable than having to retype the two larger context manager lines and has the *added* advantage that now you can run multiple commands in that same context.

As for your question; you can easily apply arbitrary arguments to a given function using the `*args` syntax:

```
def _mute(fabric_cmd, *args):
    with settings(warn_only='true'):
        with hide('running', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'warnings'):
            return fabric_cmd(*args)

def some_remote_task():
    # Run a remote task silently
    output = _mute(remote, 'uname -a')
```

See [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) for more information on the `*args` arbitrary argument lists tricks.

Comment: Thanks the @contextmanager decorator worked perfectly. I appreciate you guiding me towards the docs for those as well as the *args syntax.